# Runtime Error 424 upon Clipboard.GetText / SetText

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to copy&paste lots of texts from PDF files to Word docs, and they come with all the PDF line breaks which aren't needed to wrap text on Word, so I'm trying to write a macro that would save me lots of time if it worked, replacing line breaks with space characters at System Clipboard in between my Copy and Paste operations. This is what I've tried:

```
Sub PdfPaste()
Dim PdfPaste As String
PdfPaste = Clipboard.GetText
PdfPaste = Replace(PdfPaste, vbNewLine, " ")
Clipboard.SetText = PdfPaste
End Sub
```

This throws a Runtime Error 424 Object Required on lines 3 and 5 (Clipboard.GetText and .SetText methods).

I'm obviously a newbie, so excuse me for my ignorance if I'm terribly wrong about my approach here...

Comment: That should work with VB6, sure that's what your using as opposed to  VBA in an Office application or VB.Net?

Comment: I guess the most important part of my question was that I'm a newbie... You're right, that was it. For the record, I accomplished what I needed with the following code, which applies to VBA for Office:

`Sub ColarPDF()`

    `Dim Cola As String`
    `Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject`
    `objData.GetFromClipboard`
    `Cola = objData.GetText()`
    `Cola = Replace(Cola, vbNewLine, " ")`
    `objData.SetText Cola`
    `objData.PutInClipboard`
`End Sub`
Thanks!

Comment: Please add your own answer and accept it so this question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Alex K., I was actually using **VBA**, not **VB6**, and that's the answer to my question. The code mentioned by the question should work in VB6. 
I accomplished what I needed with the following code, which applies to **VBA** for Office:

```
Sub PastePDF() 
  Dim PdfPaste As String
  Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
  objData.GetFromClipboard
  PdfPaste = objData.GetText()
  PdfPaste = Replace(PdfPaste, vbNewLine, " ")
  objData.SetText PdfPaste
  objData.PutInClipboard 
End Sub
```